# React.js: How do I fix this hydration error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

the hydration error appears if I have this:

```
export const LoginForm = (styles: LoginProps) => (
  <>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        Email: "",
        Password: "",
      }}

    >
      <Form>
        <table>

          <tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </>
);
```

but does not appear if I have this:

```
export const LoginForm = (styles: LoginProps) => (
  <>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        Email: "",
        Password: "",
      }}

    >
      <Form>
        <table>

        </table>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </>
);
```

error:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

Other areas of the app I'm building allow the use of  and   but here it causes a "hydration error"

no matter what else I remove it seems to entirely be the  and  tags.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

as with this:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36754

the  tag cannot be used in nextJS without causing a hydration error.

However, if used with dangerously set inner HTML, as it effects the DOM directly, it does not matter.

(the other area of the website uses this to create the HTML differences)